# Constructing next-occuring python datetime from only month and day

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string representing just the month and day (format: `"%m/%d"`, e.g. "12/25") and I would like to construct a datetime for the next occurrence of it, relative to today. Ideally a function like:

```
datetime.next_strptime("12/25", "%m/%d")
# returns the 2023-12-25 datetime object, since I'm posting this question before 2023-12-25
```

I know I can write a few lines like:

```
# begins as 1900-12-25 since year is absnet
date = datetime.strptime("12/25", "%m/%d")
# set to 2023-12-25 or current year
date.replace(year=date.today().year)
# if today is actually past 2023-12-25, we'll increment it by a year
if date < date.today():
    date = date + relativedelta(years=1)
```

besides being more lines, I worry about having to write in more edge cases (this code doesn't work with `"2/29"` for instance, as 1900 and date.today().year are possibly not leap years and would raise an exception

Comment: just monkey patch `datetime.datetime` with the function you need to convert all the cases, because it is not a much needed case nobody has written these lines yet, for `2/29` you want the next leap year case, you can work with ordinal day numbers, if the constructed date is illegal it has no ordinal day number, check 4 cases with increasing year numbers until you get a valid ordinal day number

Comment: @FObersteiner this is defined in the code example. It will be the next occurrence relative to `date.today()`, inclusive.